# Automatically fill a table from another

Tags: excel, vba

In the left table I introduce the values manually, but in the right table I want to put the values from left table automatically in according with the rule.   example: if prop1=3 "in left table" then fill in right table at 25/-20 the value 2 at prop1_default=3. Can you help me with some solutions, idea, please?

[image: table]

thanks for help!

Comment: Is the data in the coloured cells of the left-hand table more or less static, i.e. it doesn't change from one occasion to the next? Or are you looking for a general purpose solution that will read any table of data in this format and produce the output on the right?

Comment: I am not interested in the color of the cells. Just a general solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a column alongside your left-hand table, say column E, enter this formula:

```
E2: =A2&"/"&B2&"/"&C2
```

and fill it down for the following rows. This creates a key you can use for lookups, e.g. in your example `E2` will contain `25/-20/4`.

Now in each cell of your right-hand table, use the formula:

```
H2: =IFERROR(INDEX($D$2:$D$7,MATCH(H$1&"/"&$G2,$C$2:$C$7,0)))
```

where `$C$2:$C$7` is the range containing the *prop1* values and `$D$2:$D$7` has the corresponding *prop2* values. This matches the appropriate *vel*/*temp*/*prop1* combination and returns the corresponding *prop2* if the combination exists, otherwise a blank. The use of `$` here means the formula will be correctly updated when you fill it across the columns and down the rows of your right-hand table.

If you want all of this completely automated, it will be possible to come up with a formula using `MATCH` and `INDEX` to generate the right-hand table headings, then you can create a template spreadsheet pre-filled with the maximum number of rows and columns you expect to need and use Paste Values to get the data into your left-hand table on each occasion. Alternatively you could write some VBA to enter all the necessary formulae and fill them down/across, in which case for the right-hand column headings you could use a loop that steps through the left-hand table rows and adds a new heading each time the combination of *vel* and *temp* changes.